# Passing arguments to socat child process

Tags: tty, socat

I am solving a challenge and I need to perform privilege escalation. Currently I have privileges of a local user.
So there is a binary which runs as root and launches shell if we pass **any** argument when running the binary.
The binary is being executed with socat with the **EXEC** command, and listening on a port at server end. However, in the **EXEC** of **socat**, no arguments have been passed so the binary doesn't run the shell. So when we connect to that port on server, it just gives me normal functionality of binary and not the shell. The command being executed on the server as root on startup is:
**socat TCP-LISTEN:1337,resuseaddr,fork EXEC:"/path/to/the/binary" &**

So from what I learnt so far, the EXEC in socat creates a child process using the execvp() call every time someone connects to the listening port on server.

Is there a way for me to pass some argument to the child process created with EXEC in socat? What I basically need is "**/path/to/the/binary anyargument**".

Comment: What is the "normal functionality of binary" exactly?